# what is loading error in op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

what is loading error in op amp?
I have a voltage regulator with zener diode and op amp.
why do voltage is low in lower loads for example 100 ohm but for higher loads is not it?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. You can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: Amplifiers have Rout and Zout. A low Rload or Zload has the effect, because of voltage division, of lowering the open-loop-gain that is available to achieve best regulation.

Comment: An opamp has no "loading error". However, if the opamp is used as a linear amplifier with a feedback loop we can observe - in some cases - a loading effect. But we need the circuit diagram....

Answer (score 1):

The Op-Amp can supply a maximum current - and we know that (using Ohms Law) the voltage is a product of the current and the resistance. If the maximum input voltage is, say, 6V, then your output will saturate at 6V if its not linear. To test this, lets forcibly create a large differential to saturate it.

However, say your maximum output current is 50mA, you cannot supply more than that. So for a load of 100 Ohms, you can supply only 50ma - which is (50mA * 100Ohm = 5V). This presents a loading error. Now, for a larger load of 200 Ohms, you can supply the full voltage and you won't saturate at the current - you can provide 6V, and the current would be (6V / 200Ohm = 30mA).

The maximum current will depend on the specific amplifier, and it could be found on the datasheet.